# Inserting the current date doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, date, doctrine, query-builder

I have created a symfony project and am having a date issue. I would like to make a request which inserts the current date in the database. In my entity my fields are date time.

Here is the repository, the controller and the error obtained.

Repository :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date_maj;
```

Controller :

```
 $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update(Tache::class, 't')
        ->set('t.date_maj', date(('Y-m-d H:i:s'), time()))
        ->where('t.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Error :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected end of string, got '06'

Answer (score 1):

You want to set a parameter with a PHP `\DateTime` as the value, similar to `:id` in the where clause. The query builder will handle the conversion to the database string value:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update(Tache::class, 't')
    ->set('t.date_maj', ':now')
    ->where('t.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('now', $now)
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your entity with persist and flush instead using queryBuilder.
Your entity looks like thhis :

```php
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @var DateTime|null
 */
private $date_maj;

public function getDateMaj(): ?DateTime
{
    return $this->date_maj;
}

public function setDateMaj(?DateTime $dateMaj): self
{
    $this->date_maj = $dateMaj;
}
```

And controller-side :

```php
// it's for example, using injection dependency is better 
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Get your entity (if it's from Form, this line is useless, retrieve entity from $form->getData())
$tache = $em->getRepository(Tache::class)->find($id);

$now = new \DateTime();
$tache->setDateMaj($now);

$em->persist($tache);
$em->flush();
```

If it's ok, you can edit typo `DateTime` to `DateTimeInterface` too

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your construct using `new \DateTime()`

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date_maj=new \DateTime();
      
    }
```